# HTML mult-text color

Tags: html, class, styles, stroke

```
    <div class="mySlides fade">  
      <img src="images/homepage1/youth_academy_black_history_2.JPG" 
      style="width:100%">
    <div class="text" style="color:black">Youth Academy</div>
```

The above code produces a picture with black text.  Lets say I want a stroke(multicolor) ie black with silver outline of the text.  In photoshop its called stroke.  Can I do this in html code??

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for -->  https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-create-a-multicolor-text-in-html-and-css.html

Answer (score 0):

```
.text {
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: red;}
```

something like this could work

or

```
.text {text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code helps you. In CSS you can use the `text-stroke` property to achieve this effect. All the Best!

```css
.text{
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.5px;   
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: red;  
  text-stroke-width: 0.5px;
  text-stroke-color: yed;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
 <div class="mySlides fade">  
      <img src="images/homepage1/youth_academy_black_history_2.JPG" 
      style="width:100%">
    <div class="text" style="color:black">Youth Academy</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The font-size has been increased in order to reflect the effect of text-stroke property of CSS. You may handle the font-size as per your convenience. Please let me know if this answer helps. Also, you could refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke link to study more about it.

```css
.mySlides.fade .text{
-webkit-text-stroke: 0.4px yellow;
text-stroke: 0.4px yellow;
color: #000000;
font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="mySlides fade">  
      <img src="images/homepage1/youth_academy_black_history_2.JPG" 
      style="width:100%">
    <div class="text" style="color:black">Youth Academy</div>
```